# Only gravitation and Newton's $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ law needed to derive Kepler's laws?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets, foundations

It is known that [Kepler's laws of planetary motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion) can be derived from [Newton's laws of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) and his [law of universal gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation). However, are all of Newton's laws of motion necessary?

According to [this website](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/KeplersLaws.htm), all of Kepler's laws can be derived from gravitation and the Newton's second law ($\mathbf{F} = m\mathbf{a}$). Does this mean that Newton's first and third laws are irrelevant for planetary motion?

Perhaps Newton's third law (action-reaction) is necessary to take into account the motion of the Sun as induced by gravitational pull from the orbiting planets, but when deriving Kepler's laws the Sun is assumed to be fixed...

Comment: If all relevant forces are gravitational, Newton's law of gravity automatically upholds Newton's third law. In the two-body sun-planet system with a finitely-massed sun, Kepler's laws still hold with appropriate substitutions (barycenter and reduced mass).

Comment: I see. So Newton's first law is irrelevant then, because every body is accelerating?

Comment: Newton's first law is basically conservation of momentum and energy, and I think you'd have to concede that's quite important when calculating orbits.

Comment: Some people consider that the first and second laws are just definitions (of inertial state and force), and carry no physical meaning. The third law is embedded in newtonian gravity.

Comment: Newton's second law is the fundamental law. The first and third laws can be derived from the second law. Thus, the second law can be said to contain the first and third laws.

Comment: Kepler's 2nd law (equal areas in equal times) does not require the inverse-square law of gravitation. It only requires that the pulling point be stationary w.r.t. the orbit.